# Running Lottie animation within each loop, but wait for animations to complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, lottie

I'm using `[lottie-web][1]` to play some SVG animations in the browser, but I need them to play one at a time, and only move onto the next once the current animation has completed.

At present, `lottie.play()` plays all the animations at once, where as I want to run them once at a time, before moving onto the next loop within `each()`.

I feel like this should be relatively simple, but struggling to make it work. I've been playing with lottie.onComplete but with no luck so far. Perhaps I need to register each animation separately?

Thanks.

**HTML**

```
<div class="step one">
    <div class="animation" data-json="JSON DATA HERE"></div>
</div>
<div class="step two">
    <div class="animation" data-json="JSON DATA HERE"></div>
</div>
<div class="step three">
    <div class="animation" data-json="JSON DATA HERE"></div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
// Vars
var steps = $('.step');

// Loop through steps
steps.each( function(){
      
    // Find animation for this step
    var animation = $(this).find('.animation');
    // Convert from jQuery to vanilla js for use with lottie-web
    var anim = animation.get(0);

    // Lottie animation (vanilla js)
    var lottie = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
        container: anim,
        renderer: 'svg',
        loop: false,
        autoplay: false, // Don't autoplay, so we can play at desired time
        path: anim.getAttribute('data-json')
    });

    // Play animation
    lottie.play(); // Plays all, but should only play current animation

    // On animation complete
    lottie.onComplete = function(){

      // On complete, proceed to next .step
      console.log('complete');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like bellow. Suppose you have three Lottie players

```
<lottie-player id="player1" src='url_to_lottie_file_1'  style=""  background="transparent" loop="false" speed="1" ></lottie-player>
<lottie-player id="player2" src='url_to_lottie_file_2'  style=""  background="transparent" loop="false" speed="1" ></lottie-player>
<lottie-player id="player3" src='url_to_lottie_file_3'  style=""  background="transparent" loop="false" speed="1" ></lottie-player>
```

Include the Lottie player plugins

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js" defer></script>
```

Now you want to start second player after first one finish. While Second one finished, start the third one.

```
let player1= document.querySelector("#player1");
let player2= document.querySelector("#player2");
let player3= document.querySelector("#player3");
       
player1.addEventListener('loop', completedLoop1);
function completedLoop1(){
    player2.play();
    //remove event listener
    player1.removeEventListener('loop', completeEvent1);            
}

player2.addEventListener('loop', completedLoop2);
function completedLoop1(){
     player3.play();
     //remove event listener
     player2.removeEventListener('loop', completeEvent2);
}
//start the animation
player1.play();
```